# React: Context Consumer in return function: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.eslint(no-unused-expressions)

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am developing a website and would like one side to be conditionally rendered depending on which value is assigned in AppContext. However, when I use AppContext.Consumer in the render function before return I get following error:

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.eslint(no-unused-expressions)

I would like to use this so I can conditionally set the value for component which I would put in return once the error is gone. Here is my current code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { IconButton, Grid, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import ArrowForward from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowForward';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CheckBoxGroup from '../utils/CheckBoxGroup';
import CheckBox from '../utils/CheckBox';
import AppContext from '../utils/AppContext';

const styles = theme => ({
  container: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    border: 'black',
    'border-width': 'medium',
    'margin-top': '80px',
    background: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)',
    'border-radius': '20px'
  },
  item: {
    width: '100%',
    'text-align': 'center',
    'border-radius': '5px',
    'margin-top': '10px'
  }
});

class FormEmergencyType extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.classes = props.classes;
    this.state = {
      lifeatdanger: props.emergencyTypes.lifeatdanger,
      injury: props.emergencyTypes.injury,
      illness: props.emergencyTypes.illness,
      poisoning: props.emergencyTypes.poisoning,
      firesmoke: props.emergencyTypes.firesmoke,
      other: props.emergencyTypes.other
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  //somehow manage global variable set on Landingpage specifying whether police or ambulance

  handleChange(event, checked) {
    let new_state = this.state;

    switch (event.target.value) {
      case 'lifeatdanger':
        new_state['lifeatdanger'] = checked;
        break;
      case 'injury':
        new_state['injury'] = checked;
        break;
      case 'illness':
        new_state['illnes'] = checked;
        break;
      case 'poisoning':
        new_state['poisoning'] = checked;
        break;
      case 'firesmoke':
        new_state['firesmoke'] = checked;
        break;
      case 'other':
        new_state['other'] = checked;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

    this.setState(new_state);
    this.props.handleEmergencyType(new_state);
  }

  //icon next to the buttons
  render() {
    let component;
    <AppContext.Consumer>; let component;</AppContext.Consumer>;
    return (
      <Grid
        container
        className={this.classes.container}
        direction="column"
        spacing={2}
      >
        <Grid item sm={12} className={this.classes.item}>
          <Typography variant="h5">Who do you want to contact?</Typography>
          <CheckBoxGroup>
            <CheckBox
              title="Life at danger"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              checked={this.state['lifeatdanger']}
              value="lifeatdanger"
            />
            <CheckBox
              title="Injury"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              checked={this.state['injury']}
              value="injury"
            />
            <CheckBox
              title="Illness"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              checked={this.state['illnes']}
              value="illnes"
            />
            <CheckBox
              title="Poisoning"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              checked={this.state['poisoning']}
              value="poisoning"
            />
            <CheckBox
              title="Fire / Smoke"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              checked={this.state['firesmoke']}
              value="firesmoke"
            />
            <CheckBox
              title="Other"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              checked={this.state['other']}
              value="other"
            />
          </CheckBoxGroup>
          <Grid />
          <Grid
            item
            sm={12}
            className={(this.classes.item, this.classes.forwardbutton)}
          >
            <IconButton
              edge="start"
              color="black"
              onClick={this.props.handleComponentType}
            >
              <ArrowForward />
            </IconButton>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(FormEmergencyType);
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: any ideas to help me?